# Using spray-json marshallers inside a generic routes function

Tags: scala, generics, spray, spray-json

I'm writing a REST service using Spray. Several of the routes I have follow an identical pattern (GET /foos, POST /foos, GET /foos/:id etc), so I'd like to factor those routes out into a generic function that I can call like `modelRoutes[Foo]("foos")`, `modelRoutes[Bar]("bars")` etc.

The actual database operations happen on the Controller[T] trait, and I have implicit `object FooController extends Controller[Foo]` etc. For example, `def getAll: List[T]` on Controller[T] and `def getAll: List[App]` on AppController.

The problem I'm having is that inside `modelRoutes[T <: Model : Controller](prefix: String)`, the type of the model is lost, so Marshaller[T] and Marshaller[List[T]] cannot be found. I've tried various permutations of implicits and manifests, without luck so far.

How can I correctly interact with the Marshaller in a generic function?

Comment: For under-the-hood questions, you may want to try the Spray forum also: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/spray-user.

Comment: Have you already tried `modelRoutes[T <: Model : Controller: Marshaller]`?

Comment: @jrudolph I didn't know you could stack type classes up like that. `modelRoutes[T <: Model : Controller : Marshaller : Unmarshaller]` seems valid, but the full `modelRoutes[T <: Model : Controller : Marshaller : Marshaller[List] : Unmarshaller]` fails on `List`.

Comment: It does seem to work if I explicitly add all the marshallers as implicit arguments, though:

`def modelRoutes[T <: Model : Controller](prefix: String)(implicit modelMarshaller: Marshaller[T], modelUnmarshaller: Unmarshaller[T], modelsMarshaller: Marshaller[List[T]])`

I'm still not entirely sure *why* that works, though. Even without that, the implicit marshallers are in scope, but the correct ones can't be resolved. I presume it must be that they can be correctly chosen and passed as arguments at the call site because that's the only place that the real type of T is known well enough?

Comment: Yes, it's because inside the method you need the generic `Marshaller[T]` which can't be inferred from the types. At the point where you call `modelRoutes` you have the concrete types, instead, and declaring the type classes at the `modelRoutes` method like above make them available in the method.

Comment: You could instead try `modelRoutes[T <: Model : Controller : JsonFormat]`. Then it should be able to find all the needed (Un)Marshallers in the method.